# ViewPager doesnot change its contents

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a viewPager, which have to prevents back swipe. here is my code

```
   public class testActivity extends FragmentActivity
   {
ViewPager pager;
LayoutInflater inflater;
List<String> qNum;
int id=1;
MyPagesAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_page);

    qNum=new ArrayList<String>();
    qNum.add("1");
    qNum.add("2");
    qNum.add("3");
    qNum.add("4");
    qNum.add("5");
    System.out.println(qNum);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    adapter=new MyPagesAdapter();

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

           id = pager.getCurrentItem();
           System.out.println("id returns "+id);

}


class MyPagesAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return qNum.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_model, container,false);
        System.out.println("current pos: "+position);

        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.numberView)).setText(String.valueOf(qNum.get(0)));
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(view, 0);

        if(position>id)
        {
            System.out.println("removes id "+qNum.get(0));
            qNum.remove(0);
            System.out.println(qNum);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            id=position;
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((view));

            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.numberView)).setText(String.valueOf(qNum.get(0)));

            ((ViewPager) container).addView(view, 0);

             return view;
        }
        else if(position==id)
        {
            System.out.println("position and id equals");
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.numberView)).setText(String.valueOf(qNum.get(0)));
           ((ViewPager) container).addView(view, 0);
            return view;
        }
        else if(position<id)
            return R.layout.finish;

          return R.layout.finish_test;  

    }

     @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0==(View)arg1;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
      ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
      object=null;
    }
}
```

}

My problem is LogCat displays the correct list after remove elements from list, but in emulator, it does not change after 2 how much times I swipe(I can just see question no 4, but when I leave finger it returns to 2). also it shows removed item when I swipe to right

My LogCat is

```
05-09 02:02:58.561: I/System.out(2252): [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
05-09 02:02:58.621: I/System.out(2252): id returns 0
05-09 02:03:01.161: I/System.out(2252): current pos: 0
05-09 02:03:01.171: I/System.out(2252): position and id equals
05-09 02:03:01.361: I/System.out(2252): current pos: 1
05-09 02:03:01.391: I/System.out(2252): removes id 1
05-09 02:03:01.391: I/System.out(2252): [2, 3, 4, 5]
05-09 02:03:28.101: I/System.out(2252): current pos: 2
05-09 02:03:28.141: I/System.out(2252): removes id 2
05-09 02:03:28.151: I/System.out(2252): [3, 4, 5]
05-09 02:03:28.351: I/System.out(2252): current pos: 2
05-09 02:03:28.381: I/System.out(2252): removes id 3
05-09 02:03:28.381: I/System.out(2252): [4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a good reference from the below document even their is a  sample project in it which can help you alot.

http://architects.dzone.com/articles/android-tutorial-using

Comment: this is just like what I did, the difference is I am implement with array, but here it with Fragments. still remains my problem, just want to swipe forward only